# When was this quote from in Bioshock Infinite?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I just finished playing this game and I love the quotes from the Lutece Twins.  I found this quote from [here](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt1712064/quotes?qt=qt1927260):

> Robert Lutece: I told you they'd come.
>
> Rosalind Lutece: No, you didn't.
>
> Robert Lutece: Right. I was going to tell you they'd come.
>
> Rosalind Lutece: But you didn't.
>
> Robert Lutece: But I don't.
>
> Rosalind Lutece: You sure that's right?
>
> Robert Lutece: I was going to have told you they'd come?
>
> Rosalind Lutece: No.
>
> Robert Lutece: The subjunctive?
>
> Rosalind Lutece: That's not the subjunctive.
>
> Robert Lutece: I don't think the syntax has being invented yet.
>
> Rosalind Lutece: It would have had to have had been.
>
> Robert Lutece: Had to have... had... been? That can't be right.

I remember this quote from the game, but I can't figure out *when* it was said in the game.  Can anyone tell me what chapter or general area it was told?

Comment: Sounds like something from 'Waiting for Godot' :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Emporia, after Booker awakens in the crashed ship, we find the Lutece Twins plinking on a piano. During the cable car to board the car to Emporia proper, you will overhear that amusing conversation between the twins.

Comment: i think this is when Robert painting Rosalind, when Elizabeth start to remember them being dead.